# Problemas com cURL usando Face++

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou utilizando uma API da Face++ para reconhecimento visual de faces.

Montei um código em PHP que envia uma `face.jpg` para a API deles de acordo com as regras na documentação, mas esse cURL ou não está enviando os dados ou não está funcionando, pois no Linux no `shell_exec` ele funciona.

Ao tentar transferir o código para PHP ele não funcionou.

Meu código de cUEL no Linux que funciona:

```
curl -X POST "https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect" -F "api_key=<api_key>" \
-F "api_secret=<api_secret>" \
-F "image_file=@image_file.jpg" \
-F "return_landmark=1" \
-F "return_attributes=gender,age"
```

Meu código em PHP que não me traz retorno:

```
$data = array(
    'api_key' => '<APIKEYAKI>', 
    'api_secret' => '<SECRETAKI>',
    'return_landmark' => '1',
    'return_attributes' => 'gender,age'
);   

$data['image_file'] = '@./jasar.jpg';

$handle = curl_init('https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/search');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$dados = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);

echo $dados;
```

ja tentei alterar códigos de PHP; peguei vários exemplos aqui mesmo no site e nada.

Segue cod atualizado que já retorna um erro mas agora não faz o post do jpg

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/search");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "api_key=123456&api_secret=32164&return_attributes=gender,age&outer_id=facesetpocface&image_file=@".realpath('jasar.jpg'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);


print($result);
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar o caminho completo até a imagem ao invés do caminho relativo?

Comment: sim cara tentei ate user aquele real_patch do php.

Comment: Tenta direcionar essa requisição com o `curl` para uma página sua e verifique se a requisição está correta.

Comment: volta em branco

Comment: A resposta, sim. Mas e a requisição? Por isso falei para fazer a requisição em uma URL sua e faça o debug das informações que chegaram.

Comment: mudei meu cod e agora retorna erro mas ele nao esta fazendo o post da minha imagem jpg vou atualizar na postagem

Comment: Faltou colocar a resposta que obteve com este novo código.

Comment: não vem nada atela fica em branco testei em vários servidores e local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tente deste jeito e me diga se funcionou**

```
$handle = curl_init('https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/search');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'api_key' => '<APIKEYAKI>', 
    'api_secret' => '<SECRETAKI>',
    'image_file' => curl_file_create(realpath('marquito.jpg')),   
    'return_landmark' => '1',
    'return_attributes' => 'gender,age'
));
$dados = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);

echo $dados;
```

Comment: voltou info agora mas ta dizendo que o image_file esta faltando.

Comment: coloquei um realpath do php e funcionou muito obrigado.